# Efficient concatenation of Bit Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap, bit

I am currently writing a piece of code where I have identified that the concatenation of my two bit arrays is the bottleneck, and debating on how to make it more efficient.

My Bit array is modelled as follows

```
public BitArray(int size) { 
    int sizeBytes = size / 8 ;
    if (size % 8 !=0) sizeBytes++;
    this.array = new byte[sizeBytes];
    this.size = size ; 
}
```

where size is the size in bits.

The challenge when concatenating two bit arrays efficiently is the straddling that needs to occur when concatenating a bit array of size 7 with one of size 6  for example. As such, 
it is not possible to simply do two array copies.

The solutions I am investigating, on top of what i currently have implemented is the following:
compute the "straddle region" (the last 3 bits of a  5 bitarray for example). 
copy the first array with system.array.copy
manually set the 3 "straddling bits" from the second array using my setBit function.
shift the second array by 3 to the left
do a `System.arraycopy()`

Currently, I manually set each individual bit of the second array, as shown below.

The issue is that with bit shifting,the operation is actually quite expensive given it has to be done for each byte, then the straddling has to occur again.

Thoughts on how to improve the techniques outlined above?

Here is the current code which performs poorly:

```
public static BitArray concatenate(BitArray x1_, BitArray x2_) {
    if (x1_ == null) {
        System.out.println("x1 is null");
        int b = x2_.getArray().length;
        byte[] array = new byte[b];
        System.arraycopy(x2_.getArray(), 0, array, 0, b);
        BitArray res = new BitArray(array);
        res.setSize(x2_.getSize());
        return res;
    } else if (x2_ == null) { 
        System.out.println("x2 is null");
        int b = x1_.getArray().length;
        byte[] array = new byte[b];
        System.arraycopy(x1_.getArray(), 0, array, 0, b);
        BitArray res = new BitArray(array);
        res.setSize(x1_.getSize());
        return res;
    }

    int size1 = x1_.getSize();
    int size2 = x2_.getSize();
    int size = (x1_.getSize() + x2_.getSize()) / 8 ;
    if ((size1 + size2)%8!=0) size++;
    byte[] result = new byte[size];
    System.arraycopy(x1, 0, result, 0, x1.length);
    BitArray res = new BitArray(result);
    res.setSize(size1 + size2);
    for (int i = 0 ; i<size2 ; i++) {
        res.setBit(size1 + i, x2_.getBit(i) );
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: First thought: use long instead of byte, this could waste 7 bytes, but may make things much faster.

Comment: Maybe you can do "virtual bit-shifting" by having an "offset" field that says where the data starts in your array?

Comment: Second thought: don't shift, concatenate byte arrays, keep the "hole" and use some mapping internally.

Comment: Third thought: If memory is not an issue, just use a whole byte for each bit. Makes copying and indexing easier. Blows up memory use x8.

Comment: Fourth thought: Why not use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)? You can use [BitSet#or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#or(java.util.BitSet)) to concatenate.

Comment: memory is definitely an issue, hence why going to the trouble of using bits :(

Comment: So memory footprint and performance is an issue then? You can't have both, you will be faster with a larger memory footprint and vice versa.

Comment: How did you find out performance of this code? Why do you think its a bottleneck? If its so much critical remove System.out.println calls. They are very expensive.

Comment: People keep bringing up BitSet#or . What does this have to do with concatenating?

Comment: @Thilo concat(10,01) = 10<<2 or 01 = 1000 or 01 = 1001. Also see [truth table for or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Truth_table)

Comment: @linski: Well, that does not solve anything, as you still need the << 2 (which is the only tricky part in the first place). BitSet does not have bit shifting, either.

Comment: @Thilo I was just answering your question, that is the probably the first implementation that comes to mind for doing a concat with or. I do not understand what is the issue with bit shifting?

Comment: @linski: Apparently, OP experiences performance problems with bit shifting a large bit field. See the part about "straddling bits". And it is non-trivial, otherwise BitSet would probably have a shift method (which it does not).

Comment: @Thilo thanks. Probably, I can't really tell. Note that [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) has such methods. Again, no clue about shifting efficiency, but it seems a bit odd.

Comment: BigInteger#shift does have a similar loop to what OP might want: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#2106

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very convoluted and difficult to read. However, a few things that can take time:

- Using the `%` operator
- calling `getSize()` multiple times in the method - why don't you use the `size` property of your bit arrays?

I think using a linked list of bytes/longs to represent your `BitArray` would make concatenating much, much faster, as you can avoid copying anything at all, just updating a pointer.

Is `concatenate` an operation you will be performing a lot on the arrays? If so, I think I would have used a linked list of longs to represent the bit array. How big are your bit arrays?

Comment: a linked list of bytes/longs does not solve this bit-shifting problem.

Comment: It might be much more efficient with huge arrays of bits. You only have to change the first and last element of the list. You don't have to shift any bits, if you implement it cleverly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can produce a new array without copying data. Something like this:

```
class MyBitArray extends BitArray{

    private BitArray a;
    private BitArray b;

    public MyBitArray(BitArray a, BitArray b) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(0);
        this.a = a == null ? new BitArray(0) : a;
        this.b = b == null ? new BitArray(0) : b;
    }

    public boolean get(int i){
        if(i < a.length()){
            return a.get(i);
        }
        return b.get(i - a.length());
    }

    public int length(){
        return a.length() + b.length();
    }
}
```